# Variables contain values but in action they equals NULL

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following js code:

```
 $("#dateRange").change(function() {
            var date = $(this).attr("value");

            var test = "1";
            var eventId = $("div.movie").attr("eventid");
            $("#scheduleList").load("/EventSchedule/GetSchedule/?date=" + date + "&dayRange=" + test + "&eventId=" + eventId);
        });
```

This is action:

```
public EmptyResult GetSchedule(string date, string dayRange, string eventId)
        {
              // some code
        }
```

In the firebug all variable filled correctly: `date` contain date, `test` contain `1` and `eventId` contain `12`. But, in controller action  `dayRange` and `evendId` equals `null`. The `date` param is filled.

Where is problem?

**UPDATE:** 
div.movie:

```
<div class="movie" eventid="12" type="Film">
  <div class="poster">
    <img src="/Image/GetImage">
    <div class="btn_buy_ticket">
      <div>
        <i></i>
        <span>
          <a href="#">Купить билет</a>
        </span>
        <em></em>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

My routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );


            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            var entryRoute = new PageEntry("page/{name}/",
                                           new RouteValueDictionary(
                                               new
                                               {
                                                   controller = "DynamicPage",
                                                   action = "Index",
                                                   name = string.Empty
                                               }),
                                               new RouteValueDictionary(new { name = @".+" }),
                                           new MvcRouteHandler());

            routes.Add("display-page",
                       entryRoute);

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Activate",
                "Account/Activate/{username}/{key}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Account",
                    action = "Activate",
                    username = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    key = UrlParameter.Optional
                });
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the `div.movie` and `selectdayRange` html?

Comment: what does dayRange contain?  have you tried hard coding values in and seeing if that gets through?

Comment: I just tried the following:`$("#scheduleList").load("/EventSchedule/GetSchedule/?date=" + date + "&eventId=5");` but `eventId` in the action equals  `NULL`. This is very strange.

Comment: Perhaps it's a routing issue.  Do you have any routes setup for this controller?

Comment: @dreza: I updated my question( add routes)

Comment: I'm thinking it's being caught by your first route.  Have you tried adding a route for this i.e. /{controller}/{action}/{date}/{dayRange}/{eventId} and add this before your default route.  Or maybe something like {date}/{*params} if you want a catch all type route?

Comment: @dreza: Error was in date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be some parameter contain white spaces.

Check that cause I have faced same problem day before yesterday..

Answer (score 0):

for `dayRange` you may want to use `$("#selectdayRange").text()`

you may also need to `encodeURIComponent($("#selectdayRange").text());` in order to be able to insert a query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the /

```
$("#scheduleList").load("/EventSchedule/GetSchedule?date=" + date ...
```

If you've never fiddled with your Global.asax file, by default, URLs route to `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

I would recommend using a ViewModel to pass your data, however, since you are using MVC.