# JQuery Grid PostData is not passing values to the controller action method - MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using JQuery grid for displaying some data on the page. I have got a list of checkboxes for applying filter to the grid which I need to pass to the controller action method. My problem is eventhough the value of the selected checkboxes are correctly retrieved before passing it the post data , it is not showing up in the controller. Intersetingly, if I am loading the page with the checkboxes selected, in that case the value is getting passed. I am very confused why this is happening. I'll be really greatful for any help. Please see the code below which I am using for binding the grid:

```
    function BindGrid() {

        var selectedPriority = [];
        $('#priority input:checked').each(function () {
            selectedPriority.push($(this).val());
        });
        var selectedState = [];
        $('#state input:checked').each(function () {
            selectedState.push($(this).val());
        });
        var selectedAckState = [];
        $('#ackState input:checked').each(function () {
            selectedAckState.push($(this).val());
        });

        var x = convertIntArrayToString(selectedPriority);
        var y = convertIntArrayToString(selectedState);
        var z = convertIntArrayToString(selectedAckState);

        jqDataUrl = "Alarm/LoadjqData";
        // Set up the jquery grid
        //$("#jqTable").jqGrid('clearGridData');
        $("#jqTable").jqGrid({
            url: jqDataUrl,
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "POST",
            postData: {
                sp: x,
                ss: y,
                sak: z
            },
            cache: false,
            // Specify the column names
            colNames: ["Id", "PointRef", "Value", "AlarmStateName", "AckStateName", "Priority", "AlarmDate"],

            // Configure the columns
            colModel: [
                { name: "AlarmId", index: "AlarmId", width: 70, align: "left" },
                { name: "PointRef", index: "PointRef", width: 200, align: "left" },
                { name: "Value", index: "Value", width: 200, align: "left" },
                { name: "AlarmStateName", index: "AlarmStateName", width: 150, align: "left" },
                { name: "AcknowledgementStateName", index: "AcknowledgementStateName", width: 170, align: "left" },
                { name: "Priority", index: "Priority", width: 100, align: "left" },
                { name: "AlarmDate", index: "AlarmDate", width: 250, align: "left" }
                ],

            // Grid total width and height
            width: 700,
            height: 250,

            // Paging
            toppager: true,
            pager: $("#jqTablePager"),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20],
            viewrecords: true, // Specify if "total number of records" is displayed

            // Default sorting
            sortname: "AlarmId",
            sortorder: "desc",

            // Grid caption
            caption: "Telemetry Alarms"
        }).navGrid("#jqTablePager",
                { refresh: true, add: false, edit: false, del: false },
                    {}, // settings for edit
                    {}, // settings for add
                    {}, // settings for delete
                    {sopt: ["cn"]} // Search options. Some options can be set on column level
             )
        //.trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1}]); 
             .trigger('reloadGrid');

    }

    function convertIntArrayToString(data) {
        var x='';
        //alert(data.length);
         for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
          x = x + data[i] + ",";
      }
      if (x != '') {
          x = x.substr(0, x.length - 1);
          //alert(x);
      }
      return x.toString();
    }

//Controller action method

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoadjqData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool _search, string searchField, string searchOper,
            string searchString, string sp, string ss, string sak)
        {

            //code ommited.
            return Json(jsonData);
        }
```

value of sp, ss and sak parameters are not apprearing in the controller.

Comment: Try this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849469/variables-contain-values-but-in-action-they-equals-null/9849726#9849726

Comment: Hi naim, thanks for the response but this post is not helping. What I have realised is grid is caching the parameters supplied via the 'PostData'. if I am unloading $("#jqTable").jqGrid('GridUnload'); the grid and then binding it then it is passing the parameters correctly. Is there any better way to stop Jquery from caching the parameters? Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post solved my problem:

[jqgrid not updating data on reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826478/jqgrid-not-updating-data-on-reload)

I had to move the code for reading the checkboxes values into a separate function and accessed that function inside the PostData and it worked like a charm. Without this it was sending the same data everytime.

Updated code is below:

```
function BindGrid() {
    var jqDataUrl = null;
    jqDataUrl = "Alarm/LoadjqData" //+ x;
    $("#jqTable").jqGrid({
        url: jqDataUrl,
        cache: false,
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",
        postData: {
            sp: function () { return getPriority(); }
        },
        // Specify the column names
        colNames: ["Id", "PointRef", "Value", "AlarmStateName", "AckStateName", "Priority", "AlarmDate"],

        // Configure the columns
        colModel: [
            { name: "AlarmId", index: "AlarmId", width: 70, align: "left" },
            { name: "PointRef", index: "PointRef", width: 200, align: "left" },
            { name: "Value", index: "Value", width: 200, align: "left" },
            { name: "AlarmStateName", index: "AlarmStateName", width: 150, align: "left" },
            { name: "AcknowledgementStateName", index: "AcknowledgementStateName", width: 170, align: "left" },
            { name: "Priority", index: "Priority", width: 100, align: "left" },
            { name: "AlarmDate", index: "AlarmDate", width: 250, align: "left" }
            ],

        // Grid total width and height
        width: 700,
        height: 250,

        // Paging
        toppager: true,
        pager: $("#jqTablePager"),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
        viewrecords: true, // Specify if "total number of records" is displayed

        // Default sorting
        sortname: "AlarmId",
        sortorder: "desc",

        // Grid caption
        caption: "Telemetry Alarms"
    }).navGrid("#jqTablePager",
            { refresh: true, add: false, edit: false, del: false },
                {}, // settings for edit
                {}, // settings for add
                {}, // settings for delete
                {sopt: ["cn"]} // Search options. Some options can be set on column level
         )
         .trigger('reloadGrid');

}

function convertIntArrayToString(data) {
    var x = '';
    //alert(data.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        x = x + data[i] + ",";
    }
    if (x != '') {
        x = x.substr(0, x.length - 1);
        //alert(x);
    }
    return x.toString();
}

function getPriority()
{
 var selectedPriority = [];
    $('#priority input:checked').each(function () {
        selectedPriority.push($(this).val());
    });
    return convertIntArrayToString(selectedPriority);

}
```